# Where is the Sitecore ASR database connection configured?

Tags: sitecore

I'm trying to set up ASR up to email scheduled reports, but this is the error message I see in the log files.

```
Exception: ASR.Reports.Items.Exceptions.DatabaseNotFoundException 
Message: Exception of type 'ASR.Reports.Items.Exceptions.DatabaseNotFoundException' was thrown. 
Source: ASR.Reports 
at ASR.Reports.Scanners.DatabaseScanner.get_Database() 
at ASR.Reports.Items.QueryScanner.Scan() 
at ASR.Interface.Report.Run(Object[] parameters) 
at ASR.Commands.ScheduledExecution.runReport(Item item, Boolean force) 
at ASR.Commands.ScheduledExecution.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__1(Item i) 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectArrayIterator`2.MoveNext() 
at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext() 
at ASR.Commands.ScheduledExecution.EmailReports(Item[] itemarray, CommandItem commandItem, ScheduleItem scheduleItem)
```

This doesn't make much sense since I'm able to generate reports through the admin interface.

In my ASR config

```xml
<setting name="ASR.ConfigurationDatabase" value="master"/>
```

In my Sitecore Analytics file

```xml
<scheduling> 
<agent type="Sitecore.Analytics.Tasks.EmailReportsTask, Sitecore.Analytics" method="Run" interval="1:00:00"> 
DatabaseName>master
```

In my connection strings config, (which I know works because everything else is working)

```xml
<add name="master" connectionString="..." ... />
```

What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing < before `DatabaseName` tag but I'm assuming this is just a typo in your question

Comment: Yep. Thanks. I actually posted this on the Sitecore Developer Network as well, but it strips out any valid XML, so I tag to remove a few brackets...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASR will use the ContentDatabase. When you run the report manually, you're running in the context of the "shell" site and it will default to master. When run as a scheduled task, the site will be "scheduler" which has no content database defined by default.

Try adding the following to a config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
  <sitecore>
    <sites>
      <site name="scheduler">
        <patch:attribute name="content">master</patch:attribute>
      </site>
   </sitecore>
</configuration>
```

Openly wondering if this is an issue to address back with the ASR module.